# How to consume basic authenticated web services exposed from WSDL for generating SSRS report?

Tags: web-services, soap, reporting-services, wsdl, ssrs-2008-r2

I have one WSDL containing the metadata like web service etc which i have tried to extract using soap API but since all the web services in WSDL are authenticated, I am not able to POST the request and get the response when I create the Data source in Report Builder and add the WSDL URL i am not able to post the request to get the required response as it throws the authentication error..!!!

I have tried setting the credentials while passing the credentials @query in dataset, but unable to post the request.

Can anyone help me on this part..!!